# AngularJS Set Default Option - ng-options

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

There are several questions like this one, but none of those worked for me.  Simply stated, using ng-options, I am getting data from a MYSQL db and I want to put the value from the DB as the selected value of a select element.  The select element populates with the list of data just fine

JS

```
$scope.cwsi = $scope.cws[3];
```

HTML - This does not work

```
<select ng-options="cw as cw.initials for cw in cws" ng-model="cwsi"></select>
```

HTML - This does work

```
<select ng-options="cw as cw.initials for cw in cws" ng-model="cws[3]"></select>
```

$scope.cws is an array of objects that contains an id, initials, and a name

What am I doing wrong here?  Thank you

Comment: Not enough code to answer. You probably try to access cws[3] before it is defined.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a dialog box in a different scope.

As the infamous Homer Simpson once said "D'oh!"